# How can i implementation a supporter chat with user (user to manager) in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub, signalr-2

I'm creating MVC5 app, and I'm already using ASP.NET Identity2.0 to create users. So, I already have the AspNetUsers table, How can i implement a chat connection between manager with a special user(not all users in a moment).

Answer (score 1):

SignalR is something you are probably looking for. [Read about it here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr). There is a lot of online examples how to implement it in MVC. It allows direct user to user connections.